# Imprimir dos listas verticalmente una al lado de otra (Python)

Tags: python-3.x

Estoy escribiendo un programa donde la entrada y la salida se produzca de la siguiente manera:

Entrada

N N N N E E N

Salida

N E N

5 7 1

Sin embargo, mi codigo imprime todo de forma vertical utilizando "\n".join(), alguna sugerencia para que imprima de la manera en que esta arriba. mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
primera_cadena=""
cadena =  input("Que direccion desea avanzar: ").split()
contador= 1

for i in range(len(cadena)-1):
    if cadena[i] == cadena[i+1]:
        contador += 1
    else:
        primera_cadena = primera_cadena + cadena[i] + str(contador)
        contador = 1
primera_cadena = primera_cadena + cadena[i+1] + str(contador)
print("\n".join(primera_cadena))
```

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Pero que es lo que hace el código?

Comment: El código no hace lo que dices. ¿Lo probastes?

Comment: No lo concatenar pors altos de línea

Comment: Si, el codigo lo he probado y efectivamente arroja lo que yo quiero, pero con el pequeño detalle que la salida es vertical y yo quiero que imprima de la forma en que presente en el ejemplo, ya he intentado con .join, .replace y aun no he podido

Comment: con respecto al enlace que dejaste candid Moe, la verdad no tanto en ese ejemplo usan librerias para resolverlo y no estoy muy familiarizado con eso. sin embargo, gracias